# How to access element in nested strong params without using [-1]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multidimensional-array, strong-parameters

I have a base controller that contains my model's allowed parameters. Here's what the simplified version looks like:

```
def order_params
  allowed_attrs = [
    :id,
    :first_name,
    { 
      art_attributes: [
        :id
      ],
      item_attributes: [
        :id,
        :art_id,
        {
          product_attributes: [
            :id,
            :item_id
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]


  if can? :manage, Order
    allowed_attrs[-1][:art_job_attributes] += [
      :artist_id,
      :ship_date
    ]
  end

  params.require(:order).permit(allowed_attrs)
end
```

My question is this: In the **if can? Manage** block, how can I access the **:art_job_attributes** element without using **[-1]**? If I amend the bottom of the **allowed_attrs** this will become a potential bug.

**.last** or **.pop** result in the same issue and looping seems like it might be too time consuming.

I thought because this is basically an array that I could do the following:

```
allowed_attrs.index(:art_job_attributes)
```

But it results in nil.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure this is a good solution for this problem, but I got it to work the way I wanted. I broke up the params. I split out the top-level variables and then composed the results at the bottom of the method. Here's what I did:

```
def order_params

  allowed_attrs = [
    :id,
    :first_name
  ]

  art_attrs = {
    art_attributes:[
      :id
    ],
    item_attributes: [
      :id,
      :art_id,
      {
        product_attributes: [
          :id,
          :item_id
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

  if can? :manage, Order
    art_attrs[:art_attributes] += [
      :ship_date,
      :artist_id
    ]
  end

  allowed_attrs.push(art_attrs)
  params.require(:order).permit(allowed_attrs)  
end
```